# Script To extract a list of AD Groups a USER is a Member OF

Tags: powershell

I have the following working script:

```
# This script Extracts , Active Drirectory Groups the user is currently a memeber-of
$users = Get-Content "C:\powershell\Permmisions\users.txt"
foreach ($user in $users){ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name | Out-File C:\Powershell\1.csv }
```

The problem is, Each line containing a group name, in the created CSV file,
Contain extra spaces charcters which i have to delete. is there a way to extract the following information to CSV or TXT , without the extra spaces i get?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of out-file use export-csv

Answer (score 1):

You just need to substitute `out-file` with `export-csv` as below:

```
# This script Extracts , Active Drirectory Groups the user is currently a memeber-of
$users = Get-Content "C:\powershell\Permmisions\users.txt"
foreach ($user in $users){ 
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | select name | export-csv C:\Powershell\1.csv -notypeinfo -append
}
```